# Check if a string contains a certain set of characters? (duplicate characters might be needed)

Tags: c#

I know there are plenty of ways to check if a string contains certain characters, but I'm trying to figure out a way of excluding duplicate letters.

So for instance, we have the string "doaurid" (random letters entered by the user)
And they type the word "dad" to see if it's valid

I can't figure out a simple solution to check if that string has 2 D's and one A.
the only way I've thought of is to use nested for loops and go through every single element in a char array and convert used letters to 1 or something

Comment: I don't understand "I'm trying to figure out a way of excluding duplicate letters". Do you want to check if the larger string contains all letters with the same count of the other string or what are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
var userInput = "doaurid";
var toCheck = "dad";

var check = toCheck.GroupBy(c=> c).ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Count());
var input = userInput.GroupBy(c=> c).ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Count());

bool validMatch = check.All(g => input.ContainsKey(g.Key) && input[g.Key] == g.Value);
```

This will only be valid if the `userInput` string contains all of the letters in `toCheck`, and *the exact same number of letters*.

If the input string can allow more duplicated letters (ie: if `"dddoauriddd"` should match), the check could be done via:

```
bool validMatch = check.All(g => input.ContainsKey(g.Key) && input[g.Key] >= g.Value);
```

Comment: hm.. if the input contains three `d`s this returns false. Not sure if that was what was asked..

Comment: @Default Wasn't sure - edited to include how to make that valid, if its desired.

Comment: Not sure either :) the specs are a bit fuzzy. But +1 since you include both solutions

Answer (score 1):

Reed Copsey's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22184190/3010968) is correct.Anyway here is another alternative with `LINQ`:

```
 var userInput = "doaurid";
 var searchWord = "dad";

 var control = userInput.Where(searchWord.Contains).Count() == searchWord.Length;
```

Comment: @ReedCopsey right :/ I couldn't see the big picture.I will fix it in a minute.

Comment: @ReedCopsey this one is OK right ? I think it should work like your first solution.

Comment: Yes - It won't handle if "ddoaurid" is a match, though.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility for this is using regular expressions. For instance, the following code will detect whether or not the supplied string contains any duplicate letters.

```
var expression = new Regex(@"(?<letter>\w).*\k<letter>");
if (expression.IsMatch(userInput)) {
    Console.WriteLine("Found a duplicate letter: {0}",  expression.Match(userInput).Groups["letter"].Value);
}
```

This expression works by first matching any word character, and then storing that result in the "letter" group. It then skips over 0 or more other intervening letters and finally matches a "backreference" to whatever it captured in the "letter" group. If a string doesn't contain any duplicate letters, this regular expression will not match - so if it matches, you know it contains duplicates, and you know at least one of those duplicates by examining the value it captured in the letter group.

In this case, it would be case sensitive. If you wanted it to be case insensitive, you could pass the RegexOptions.IgnoreCase argument to the constructor of your regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

Another apporach, using `ToLookup`:

```
var charCount = "dad".ToLookup(chr => chr);
bool allSame = charCount.All(g => g.Count() == "doaurid".Count(c => c == g.Key));
```

Answer (score 0):

I could think of a simpler solution like this

```
var userInput = "dddoauriddd"; //"doaurid";
var toCheck = "dad";
var toCheckR = "";
foreach(var c in toCheck)
{
    toCheckR += ".*";
}
Console.WriteLine(Regex.IsMatch(userInput, toCheckR));
```